# Error with selecting objects within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am writing code for a board game app. I have written a simple piece of code to determine the player's position with a mathrandom. The outcome of the mathrandom tells an array to select 1 of 4 objects (the players) and to add the outcome to their position. I also added a piece of code at the start of the function to move up in the array and select the next player so each time you click the "roll dice" button another player gets more value to their position.

The problem is that after i've gone through the entire array and arrive back at the [0] position it runs the code twice so the first player gets the function twice and all the other players get it only once.

this is my code:

```
var players = [
{name: "Player 1", positie: 0},
{name: "Player 2", positie: 0},
{name: "Player 3", positie: 0},
{name: "Player 4", positie: 0}
];
var position = 0;
var currentPlayer = players[position];

function rolClick(){
currentPlayer = players[position++];
if (position > players.length){
    position = 0;
    currentPlayer = players[position];
}
var rollen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
if (rollen === 1){
    currentPlayer.positie += 1;
    console.log("het is 1")
}else if(rollen === 2){
    currentPlayer.positie += 2;
    console.log("het is 2")
}else if(rollen === 3){
    currentPlayer.positie += 3;
    console.log("het is 3")
}else if(rollen === 4){
    currentPlayer.positie += 4;
    console.log("het is 4")
}else if(rollen === 5){
    currentPlayer.positie += 5;
    console.log("het is 5")
}else if(rollen === 6){
    currentPlayer.positie += 6;
    console.log("het is 6")
}else {
    console.log("Oops, er is iets fout gegaan.")
};
console.log(currentPlayer);
};
```

Comment: Just return from the function in the first if conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button>
  Rol de dobbelsteen
</button>
<span></span>
```

**Javascript**

```
var players = [
{name: "Player 1", positie: 0},
{name: "Player 2", positie: 0},
{name: "Player 3", positie: 0},
{name: "Player 4", positie: 0}
];
var position = 0;
var currentPlayer = null;

function rolClick(){
  if (position >= players.length){
      position = 0;
  }
  console.log("Position", position);
  currentPlayer = players[position++];

   var rollen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   currentPlayer.positie += rollen;
   $("span").html("Je hebt " + rollen + " gerold voor " + currentPlayer.name);
};

$("button").click(function() {
    rolClick();
});
```

---

```js
var players = [{
  name: "Player 1",
  positie: 0
}, {
  name: "Player 2",
  positie: 0
}, {
  name: "Player 3",
  positie: 0
}, {
  name: "Player 4",
  positie: 0
}];
var position = 0;
var currentPlayer = null;

function rolClick() {
  if (position >= players.length) {
    position = 0;
  }
  console.log("Position", position);
  currentPlayer = players[position++];

  var rollen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  currentPlayer.positie += rollen;
  $("span").html("Je hebt " + rollen + " gerold voor " + currentPlayer.name);
};

$("button").click(function() {
  rolClick();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Rol de dobbelsteen
</button>
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you first set the `currentPlayer` before the `rolClick()` function is called, and then reset/update `currentPlayer` before the 'dice' is rolled.   See the commented part below...

```
var players = [
    {
        name: 'Player 1',
        positie: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Player 2',
        positie: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Player 3',
        positie: 0
    },
    {
        name: 'Player 4',
        positie: 0
    }
];
var position = 0;

// currentPlayer is set to player 1
var currentPlayer = players[position];

function rolClick() {
    // currentPlayer is now set to player 2
    currentPlayer = players[position++];

    if (position // ... etc etc ...

}
```

To get over this update `currentPlayer` at the end of the `rolClick()` function rather than at the beginning.

In addition, you might want to look into using a `switch()` statement to replace that list of if-else-if filtering.  More on that at [MDN HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Hope that helps. :)